# No artifacts found. CircleCI and CodeClimate integration (Node,Mocha,Istanbul)

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, istanbul, circleci, code-climate

Istanbul puts everything into coverage folder.

In circle.yaml I set the below ENV var as artifact folder.

`CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS: ~/proj_name/coverage`

CircleCI doesn't seem to find artifacts. Build says no atrifacts found.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

CircleCI started to collect artifacts after setting this config:

```
general:
  artifacts:
    - "~proj_name/coverage"
```